# Difference between Partition and Page in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What is the difference between partition and page in SQL Server? Is these are available by default or we need to create explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx) is the most basic element of storage in SQL Server.

> In SQL Server, the page size is 8 KB. This means SQL Server databases
>   have 128 pages per megabyte. Each page begins with a 96-byte header
>   that is used to store system information about the page. This
>   information includes the page number, page type, the amount of free
>   space on the page, and the allocation unit ID of the object that owns
>   the page.

[Partition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx):- Partitioning allows a table, index, or index-organized table to be subdivided into smaller pieces, where each piece of such a database object is called a **partition**. Each partition has its own name, and may optionally have its own storage characteristics. The data of partitioned tables and indexes is divided into units that can be spread across more than one filegroup in a database. The data is partitioned horizontally, so that groups of rows are mapped into individual partitions.

> SQL Server 2012 supports up to 15,000 partitions by default. In
>   earlier versions, the number of partitions was limited to 1,000 by
>   default. On x86-based systems, creating a table or index with more
>   than 1000 partitions is possible, but is not supported.

Comment: But what is Partition?

Comment: @user960567:- I would say it is concept for a vertical structure that divides or separates

Comment: and how can we relate a page with a partition?

Comment: @user960567:- Or more clearly Partitioning allows a table, index, or index-organized table to be subdivided into smaller pieces, where each piece of such a database object is called a partition. Each partition has its own name, and may optionally have its own storage characteristics.

Comment: @user960567:- The above link gives the answer clearly:- The minimum size for each sort table, for each partition, is 40 pages, with 8 kilobytes per page. For example, a nonaligned partitioned index with 100 partitions requires sufficient memory to serially sort 4,000 (40 * 100) pages at the same time. If this memory is available, the build operation will succeed, but performance may suffer. If this memory is not available, the build operation will fail. Alternatively, an aligned partitioned index with 100 partitions requires only sufficient memory to sort 40 pages,

Comment: because the sorts are not performed at the same time.

Comment: OK Thanks. Is SQL Server internally create page and partition or we have to enable it explicitly

Comment: @user960567:- Partinioning is a famous concept and you have to do it externally.

Comment: I have not create/enabled partition but why I need to check sys.partition for finding objects.